# oracle protocol adapter error.

Tags: oracle, database-administration, oracle-net-services

cannot connect to the database.
Tried all possible ways of restarting the listener,checking on the firewall of port 1521, Restarting the ORACLE SERVICE but the error still persists.
For the first time after restarting the TNS listener tnsping  command is showing completed succesfully ,from the next tnsping it is showing TNS -ERROR : no Listner and the status of the listener showing "Failed to process string".
Please help where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using Windows as Platform. in this case you should check service of oracle in services.msc and start it.problem doesn't relates to listener.

Comment: I have restarted them but of no use.

Comment: is there multiple oracle home in your system? can you check it in cmd using path command? if this is the case set correct home and check it again.